# Css hover not effect with bottom and right margin

Tags: css, hover, margin

I have this css code

```
#menu:hover img
{
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
```

and html

```
<figure id="menu">

    <img src="demo HTML/CaptionHoverEffects/demo 1/images/1.png"/>
    <figcaption class="content">
        <h3>Settings</h3>
        <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
        <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1116685-Settings">Take a look</a>
    </figcaption>


</figure>
```

At css code, when I change `margin-bottom` to `margin-left` or `margin-right`, it safe run, but with `margin-bottom`, it's not effect. How can I solve it?

Comment: your code is working. I mean margin bottom do works with your hover css.

Comment: @John: It doesn't work with margin bottom, Did you try it? thanks.

Comment: your code worked for me also

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6n9vc19t/ try checking this fiddle I made its working :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
#menu:hover img {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<figure id="menu">

  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  <figcaption class="content">
    <h3>Settings</h3>
    <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
    <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1116685-Settings">Take a look</a>
  </figcaption>


</figure>
```

Comment: How your code difference with my code ? it still doesn'n work.

Comment: you need margin-bottom which you get this when you hover on image the setting text move because of margin then you should decide what you exactly want